# r shiny - reset vertical scrollbar to top upon change of inputId

Tags: r, shiny, scrollbar

Using `sidebarLayout()`, I am producing a gallery of pictures from selected values as `radioButtons()`. If, however, I scroll down a bit and then select a different value, I want the scroll bar to reset to the top.

Below is a reproducable ('copy-paste') example. To visualise the problem: (1) scroll all the way down to the last picture of the first option on the left, and (2) then select the second option, also scroll all the way down here, and (3) then go back to the first option.

You should see that (unlike what I'd like) the scrollbar does not go back to the top.

```
library(shiny)

species <- c(rep("Archaeolacerta bedriagae",5),rep("Bombina variegata",5))
photo <- c("https://www.hylawerkgroep.be/jeroen/files/0048/IMG_9055.jpg",
          "https://www.hylawerkgroep.be/jeroen/files/0048/IMG_9941.jpg",
          "https://www.hylawerkgroep.be/jeroen/files/0048/IMG_8674.jpg",
          "https://www.hylawerkgroep.be/jeroen/files/0046/IMG_7534.jpg",
          "https://www.hylawerkgroep.be/jeroen/files/0048/IMG_9635.jpg",
          "https://www.hylawerkgroep.be/jeroen/files/0045/IMG_2704.jpg",
          "http://www.hylawerkgroep.be/jeroen/files/0051/IMG_4158.jpg",
          "https://www.hylawerkgroep.be/jeroen/files/ugent_16_tr/171_7174.jpg",
          "https://www.hylawerkgroep.be/jeroen/files/0039/288_8898.jpg",
          "https://www.hylawerkgroep.be/jeroen/files/ugent_16_tr/Greece2004_23.jpg")
data <- data.frame(species,photo, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ui = fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Species",
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(width=2, radioButtons(inputId = "species1", selected = sort(unique(data$species))[1], label = NULL,
                                                     choices = c(sort(unique(data$species))))),
               mainPanel(width = 10,
                         fluidRow(
                           tags$head(tags$style(type = "text/css", "#tPanel4 {height:75vh !important;}")),
                           column(6,
                                  fluidRow(
                                    column(12, wellPanel(id = "tPanel4", style = "overflow-y: scroll; font-size: 14px", htmlOutput("gallery")))))))))))  


server = function(input, output, session) {  
  output$gallery <- renderText({
    galdat <- data[data$species==input$species1 & data$photo!= "NO", ]
    galdat$picstring <- paste0("<img src='",galdat$photo,"' width=600 /><br<br><hr>")
    string <- paste(galdat$picstring, collapse = " ")
    string
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, options = list(launch.browser=TRUE))
```

Can I force the vertical scrollbar to reset to the top every time the value of inputId is changed (and regardless of the length of the content on the right)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `library(shinyjs)` for this:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(V8)

jsCode <- "shinyjs.scrolltop = function() {tPanel4.scrollTo(0, 0)};" 

species <- c(rep("Archaeolacerta bedriagae",5),rep("Bombina variegata",5))
photo <- c("https://www.hylawerkgroep.be/jeroen/files/0048/IMG_9055.jpg",
           "https://www.hylawerkgroep.be/jeroen/files/0048/IMG_9941.jpg",
           "https://www.hylawerkgroep.be/jeroen/files/0048/IMG_8674.jpg",
           "https://www.hylawerkgroep.be/jeroen/files/0046/IMG_7534.jpg",
           "https://www.hylawerkgroep.be/jeroen/files/0048/IMG_9635.jpg",
           "https://www.hylawerkgroep.be/jeroen/files/0045/IMG_2704.jpg",
           "http://www.hylawerkgroep.be/jeroen/files/0051/IMG_4158.jpg",
           "https://www.hylawerkgroep.be/jeroen/files/ugent_16_tr/171_7174.jpg",
           "https://www.hylawerkgroep.be/jeroen/files/0039/288_8898.jpg",
           "https://www.hylawerkgroep.be/jeroen/files/ugent_16_tr/Greece2004_23.jpg")
data <- data.frame(species,photo, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ui = fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  extendShinyjs(text = jsCode, functions = c("scrolltop")),
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Species",
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(width=2, radioButtons(inputId = "species1", selected = sort(unique(data$species))[1], label = NULL,
                                                  choices = c(sort(unique(data$species))))),
               mainPanel(width = 10,
                         fluidRow(
                           tags$head(tags$style(type = "text/css", "#tPanel4 {height:75vh !important;}")),
                           column(6,
                                  fluidRow(
                                    column(12, wellPanel(id = "tPanel4", style = "overflow-y: scroll; font-size: 14px", htmlOutput("gallery")))))))))))  


server = function(input, output, session) {  
  
  observeEvent(input$species1, {
    js$scrolltop()
  })
  
  output$gallery <- renderText({
    galdat <- data[data$species==input$species1 & data$photo!= "NO", ]
    galdat$picstring <- paste0("<img src='",galdat$photo,"' width=600 /><br<br><hr>")
    string <- paste(galdat$picstring, collapse = " ")
    string
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, options = list(launch.browser=TRUE))
```

Comment: Excellent! Did have to install the packages 'V8' as well, though, but does what it should, thanks!

Comment: Ah, sorry. I always forget it - edited my answer accordingly.